# How to instantiate an inner-class inside of another inner-class

Tags: java

I am trying to instantiate a nested class InnerClassB inside of another nested class InnerClassA, so might call the `someMethodInB()` method.

Both nested classes are incumbent in the same parent class.

```
public class Outer {

     private class InnerClassA {

     InnerClassB innerClassB= new innerClassB();
     innerClassB.someMethodInB();

     }

     private class InnerClassB {

          void someMethodInB(){}
     }
}
```

I get this error

> unknown class: innerClassB.someMethodInB()

Comment: Seems to work here if I correct the typo and put the code involving the `innerClassB` variable inside of a block: http://ideone.com/Nse9t8

Comment: The call to `someMethodInB()` is not inside a method (or initializer block).

Comment: Do you get the instance of innerClassB? or you get error on instantiate

Comment: @progrAmmar The error is a compile error, not runtime.

Comment: @Radiodef Yeah, its working. Why is that?

Comment: @the_prole Because you cannot write code outside of a method (or initializer block). Only field and inner class declarations.

Comment: What if you make the method `someMethodInB` public or protected?

Comment: @progrAmmar The access modifiers don't matter here. Everything inside the class `Outer` can access the members of everything else. Accessibility of private members deals with the top-level class only. (See [6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works ,

```
    public class TestSO {
    private class InnerClassA {

    void test(){    
     InnerClassB innerClassB= new InnerClassB();
     innerClassB.someMethodInB();
    }
     }

     private class InnerClassB {

          void someMethodInB(){}
     }
     }
```

First up in Java you cannot have statements directly inside the class. That is it will not execute in the heap space.
So you need to wrap the invocation of `someMethodinB` inside a method in `InnerClassA`.
That and the typo corrected will make this work.